# Generate PDF with CSS and Images

Tags: css, image, pdf

Using Symfony2.3.4

I'm generating PDF docs with this bundle: [SpraedPDFGeneratorBundle](https://github.com/stedekay/SpraedPDFGeneratorBundle) and this is its main php class(I think):[PDFGenerator.php](https://github.com/stedekay/SpraedPDFGeneratorBundle/blob/master/PDFGenerator/PDFGenerator.php)

I managed to generate them just fine but I don't know how to set the fontPath parameter for generating a css-modified PDF with some images in it too.
Here:

```
///XController.php
$pdfGenerator = $this->get('spraed.pdf.generator');
$pdf = $pdfGenerator->generatePDF($postData/* , 
'UTF-8', array(<SOME_PATH_I_GUESS>) */);
```

the first param is the html data to be output to the PDF, the second one I kinda guessed it but I'm not sure and the third is the fontPath.

The image thing is also something I would appreciate tips about...

Has anyone ever worked with this bundle or some like it; if yes can you please help me?

Answer (score 5):

Alright I found the answer.

You are asking two things: **how to add images** and **how to add new fonts**.

## Adding Images

This is pretty simple. Assuming you're using Twig, you would need to do the following:

```
<img src="{{ app.request.scheme ~'://' ~ app.request.httpHost ~ asset("img/MyImage.png") }}" />
```

Of course you can also make this a macro so you don't repeat yourself all over the place, like this.

```
{% macro image(uri) %}
{{ app.request.scheme ~'://' ~ app.request.httpHost ~ asset(uri) }}
{% endmacro %}
```

And you use it like this

```
{% import '::imgurimacro.html.twig' as img %}
...
<img src="{{ img.image('img/MyImage.png') }}" />
```

And it should work.

## Adding Fonts

This one is a bit more complex. First make sure you have the latest Spraed PDF Generator version. In composer.json:

```
"spraed/pdf-generator-bundle": "dev-master"
```

Whenever you must add the fonts to your new PDF, do the following:

```
$pdf = $pdfGenerator->generatePDF($postData , 'UTF-8', array('C:\Windows\Fonts\Font1.ttf', 'C:\Windows\Fonts\Font2.ttf'));
```

Next, create a `fonts` folder (or any name of your choice) in the `web` folder (or wherever you're placing your assets) and add the .ttf files there.

In your Twig file, add the following as a CSS style:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "MyFontFamily";
    src: {{ app.request.scheme ~'://' ~ app.request.httpHost ~ asset('fonts/Font1.ttf') }};
}
```

Now whenever you write

```
<p style="font-family: MyFontFamily">Hello World!</p>
```

It should print "Hello World!" using the registered font in the pdf.