# SpraedPDFGeneratorBundle : Generate PDF with CSS

Tags: symfony, pdf-generation

I'm trying to generate a PDF document from a Twig HTML Page using [SpraedPDFGeneratorBundle](https://github.com/stedekay/SpraedPDFGeneratorBundle), but the problem is that my stylesheet is not supported.

Somewhere I followed this question : [Generate PDF with CSS and Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23447119/generate-pdf-with-css-and-images) and I I tried to do like that:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ app.request.scheme ~'://'~ app.request.httpHost ~ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" />
```

But I'm getting an error:

> The exit status code '1' says something went wrong: stderr: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox cannot be cast to org.xhtmlrenderer.newtable.TableBox at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:127) at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:139) at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:139) at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:139) at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.jav:..

Can someone help me ?

Comment: what type of error you are getting?

Comment: this is the error I'm gettting : `The exit status code '1' says something went wrong:
stderr: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox cannot be cast to org.xhtmlrenderer.newtable.TableBox
at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:127)
at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:139)
at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:139)
at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:139)
at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.jav:..`

Comment: when I run the PDF generation operation, it gives me the above error. While when I remove the line of the style sheet, I have a document without formatting.

Comment: Try to point it a local css-file without any twig manipulation

Comment: I assume you use the Twig asset() function for displaying urls to CSS files. 
In that case the you have to prepend {{ app.request.scheme ~  '://' ~  app.request.host ~ app.request.basepath }} to get the full url.

Comment: I finally discovered that the problem is at my bootstrap stylesheet. I tried to just change the style sheet by creating a simple css file, and I see that the formatting is applied correctly.: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ app.request.scheme ~'://'~ app.request.httpHost ~ asset('css/my_custom_stylesheet.css') }}" />`

Comment: thank you for your ideas! they inspired me.

Answer (score 0):

It is mentioned somewhere in the [SpraedPDFGeneratorBundle github page](https://github.com/stedekay/SpraedPDFGeneratorBundle) this:

> To define proper print css you might want to read into the w3.org's
>   hints on that: w3.org

One of my problem was the fact that the SpraedPDFGeneratorBundle could not correctly parse the CSS file I passed him. This is the CSS file Twitter bootstrap (the version I used):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ app.request.scheme ~'://'~ app.request.httpHost ~ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" />
```

After changing the CSS file, I replaced my own stylesheet, everything worked properly because SpraedPDFGeneratorBundle was properly validate my stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ app.request.scheme ~'://'~ app.request.httpHost ~ asset('css/my_custom_stylesheet.css') }}" />
```