# CSS with SpraedPDFGeneratorBundle

Tags: css, symfony, pdf

I'm generating pdf file on `symfony2` using `SpraedPDFGeneratorBundle`.
My problem is that this bundle generates this error only when specifying a path to a css file:

> link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ app.request.scheme ~'://'~ app.request.httpHost ~ asset('assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css') }}"

```
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "The exit status code '1' says something went wrong: stderr: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox cannot be cast to org.xhtmlrenderer.newtable.TableBox at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:127) at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:139) at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:139) at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:139) at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:46) at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.Layer.paint(Layer.java:314) at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.paintPage(ITextRenderer.java:384) at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.writePDF(ITextRenderer.java:348) at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.createPDF(ITextRenderer.java:315) at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.createPDF(ITextRenderer.java:280) at com.spraed.flyingsaucer.PDFGenerator.main(PDFGenerator.java:98) " stdout: "" command: java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar "C:\wamp\www\EchriliPro\vendor\spraed\pdf-generator-bundle\Spraed\PDFGeneratorBundle/Resources/java/spraed-pdf-generator.jar" --html "C:\Windows\TEMP\tmp5593ef4087c76." --pdf "C:\Windows\TEMP\output5593ef4087c76.pdf" --encoding UTF-8." at C:\wamp\www\EchriliPro\vendor\spraed\pdf-generator-bundle\Spraed\PDFGeneratorBundle\PDFGenerator\PDFGenerator.php line 175
```

Comment: Maybe it's not able to parse `bootstrap.css`.Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28764146/spraedpdfgeneratorbundle-generate-pdf-with-css

Comment: However if I write css classes in <style> it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. As commented in this [issue](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy/issues/159) your asset URLs need to be absolute.

This can be accomplished in symfony using the asset twig funtion and "package urls":

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#assets-base-urls